# How to make select2 dropdown using Ajax Data Source with each new request?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 js for multiple optgroup inside select Box.. I am getting formatted JSON from AJAX Success Call, below is my code. It's appending to select box but its merging with existing data. I want to show only Return Ajax Data in the select box.. I have tried with select destroy and reinialize but it's not working. Please help me on how to make new data only populate in select2.[image]

```
$.post('/get_ajax_data/',{custom_param:1}, function(data){ 
        var result = data.result; 
        $("#client1_select").select2({ data:result }); 
        $('#client1_select').trigger("change"); 
    });
```

Comment: @gaetanoM data:result is not having any duplicate.. its fresh data only.. but its appending to existing select box values thats the problem.

Comment: There is no duplicates I am sure.. this is result data

{"result": [{"text": "ClientName + Version data is AJAX", "children": [{"id": "test1", "text": "test1", "disabled": true}, {"id": "test2", "text": "test2", "selected": "true", "disabled": false}, {"id": "test3", "text": "test3", "disabled": true}]}, {"text": "Variant", "children": [{"id": "1_variant", "text": "single"}, {"id": "2_variant", "text": "dual"}]}]}

Comment: @gaetanoM issue is an existing select box is not replacing with new data but it's just appending with old data..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197299/discussion-between-vijaysinh-parmar-and-gaetanom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> issue is an existing select box is not replacing with new data but it's just appending with old data..

You need to [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) the select before adding new items (I used a button to simulate ajax call):

```js
var result = [{
    "text": "ClientName + Version data is AJAX",
    "children": [{"id": "test1", "text": "test1", "disabled": true}, {
        "id": "test2",
        "text": "test2",
        "selected": "true",
        "disabled": false
    }, {"id": "test3", "text": "test3", "disabled": true}]
}, {
    "text": "Variant",
    "children": [{"id": "1_variant", "text": "single"}, {"id": "2_variant", "text": "dual"}]
}];


$('#client1_select').select2({data: result});
$('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
    $("#client1_select").empty().select2({data: result});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<select id="client1_select" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```